# How to include a long list of authors in the ACL template?

Tags: line-breaking, author

I'm working on a paper that has ~15 set of authors that is written in Latex using the ACL template. I can't seem to find a way to fit the author affiliations into the space and at the sometime increase the size of the box for author information.

I'm using the ACL template https://github.com/acl-org/acl-style-files

This is my current code and how it looks.

[image: Current Layout]

The latex code.

```
\pdfoutput=1

\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{EACL2023}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{inconsolata}


\title{Paper with extra long set of authors and institutes that is extra annoying\footnote{Corresponding Author - Author 1 with email}}

\author[1]{\bf John Doe}
\author[2]{\bf John Doe}
\author[3]{\bf John Doe}
\author[4]{\bf John Doe}
\author[4]{\bf John Doe}
\author[5]{\\ \bf John Doe}
\author[4]{\bf John Doe}
\author[4]{\bf John Doe}
\author[6]{\bf John Doe}
\author[1]{\bf John Doe}
\author[7]{\\\bf John Doe}
\author[4]{\bf John Doe}
\author[4]{\bf John Doe}
\author[6]{\bf John Doe}
\author[1]{\bf John Doe}
\author[12]{\\ \bf John Doe}
\author[4]{\bf John Doe}
\author[4]{\bf John Doe}
\author[6]{\bf John Doe}
\author[1]{\bf John Doe}

\affil[1]{Independent}
\affil[2]{John Doe Inc}
\affil[3]{Jane Doe, Inc}
\affil[4]{Random, Inc}
\affil[5]{Silicon Valley}
\affil[6]{Pied Piper}
\affil[7]{\LaTeX}
\affil[8]{\LaTeX University}
\affil[9]{\LaTeX Platforms}
\affil[10]{\LaTeX Inc}
\affil[11]{Hooli}
\affil[12]{\LaTeX Institute}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract} 
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\section{Competition Introduction}
\lipsum
```

I've used the `authorblk` package to get it streamlined but can't figure out how to get it extra space.

I'm trying to match this to the layout from this;
[image: Expectation]

And to add a footnote to the last author to mention "this is the corresponding author and email john@doe.com".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can get your response yourself easily.
To access the paper in latex format from arXiv, follow these steps:

1. Begin by downloading the paper from the provided link:

   ```
   https://arxiv.org/e-print/2103.12028
   ```
2. After downloading the file, modify its name to match the following format: `210312028.tar.gz`.
3. By renaming the file in this manner, you will gain access to the LaTeX version of the arXiv paper. This will allow you to examine the tex behind it.

I checked it my self, it's nothing special, they handle it manually:

```
% Author information does not appear in the pdf unless the "acceptedWithA" option is given
% See tacl2018v2.sty for other ways to format author information
\author{ \bf
Julia Kreutzer$^{a,b}$, 
Isaac Caswell$^a$,  
Lisa Wang$^a$,   
Ahsan Wahab$^c$, 
Daan van Esch$^a$,\\
\bf 
Nasanbayar Ulzii-Orshikh$^{d}$, 
Allahsera Tapo$^{b,e}$, 
Nishant Subramani$^{b,\delta}$, 
Artem Sokolov$^a$, \\
\bf
Claytone Sikasote$^{b,g}$, 
Monang Setyawan$^h$,
Supheakmungkol Sarin$^{h}$,
\\
\bf 
Sokhar Samb$^{b,i}$,  
Benoît Sagot$^{j}$,
Clara Rivera$^a$, 
Annette Rios$^{k}$,  
Isabel Papadimitriou$^{l}$,  \\
\bf 
Salomey Osei$^{b,m}$, 
Pedro Ortiz Suarez$^{j, n}$, %Pedro Javier Ortiz Suárez$^{j, n}$, 
Iroro Orife$^{b,o}$, 
Kelechi Ogueji$^{b,p}$,  \\
\bf 
Andre Niyongabo Rubungo$^{b,q}$, 
Toan Q. Nguyen$^{r}$, 
Mathias Müller$^{k}$, 
André Müller$^{k}$,\\
\bf
Shamsuddeen Hassan Muhammad$^{b,s}$,  
Nanda Muhammad$^{h}$,
Ayanda Mnyakeni$^{h}$, \\
\bf
Jamshidbek Mirzakhalov$^{c,t}$,  
Tapiwanashe Matangira$^h$, 
Colin Leong$^{b}$,
Nze Lawson$^h$,  \\
\bf  
Sneha Kudugunta$^a$, 
Yacine Jernite$^{b,u}$, 
Mathias Jenny$^{k}$, 
Orhan Firat$^{a,c}$, 
 \\
\bf 
Bonaventure F. P. Dossou$^{b,v}$, 
Sakhile Dlamini$^h$, 
Nisansa de Silva$^{w}$,  
Sakine Çabuk Ballı$^{k}$, \\
\bf 
Stella Biderman$^{x}$, 
Alessia Battisti$^{k}$, 
Ahmed Baruwa$^{b,y}$, 
Ankur Bapna$^a$,  \\
\bf 
Pallavi Baljekar$^a$, 
Israel Abebe Azime$^{b,i}$, 
Ayodele Awokoya$^{b,z}$, 
Duygu Ataman$^{c, k}$,  \\
\bf 
Orevaoghene Ahia$^{b,\alpha}$, 
Oghenefego Ahia$^{h}$, 
Sweta Agrawal$^{\beta}$, 
Mofetoluwa Adeyemi$^{b,\gamma}$, \\ \\

$^a$Google Research, $^b$Masakhane NLP, $^c$Turkic Interlingua, $^d$Haverford College, \\
$^e$RobotsMali, $^f$Intel Labs, $^g$University of Zambia, $^h$Google,  $^i$AIMS-AMMI,\\
$^j$Inria,
 $^k$University of Zurich, $^l$Stanford University,\\
 $^m$Kwame Nkrumah University of Science and Technology,\\
 $^n$Sorbonne Université, $^o$Niger-Volta LTI, $^p$University of Waterloo\\
$^q$University of Electronic Science and Technology of China, $^r$University of Notre Dame, \\
$^{s}$Bayero University Kano, $^{t}$University of South Florida, $^{u}$Hugging Face,  \\
$^{v}$Jacobs University Bremen,
 $^{w}$University of Moratuwa, $^{x}$EleutherAI, \\
 $^{y}$Obafemi Awolowo University, $^{z}$University of Ibadan,
 $^{\alpha}$Instadeep, \\
$^{\beta}$University of Maryland,
$^{\gamma}$Defence Space Administration Abuja,\\
$^{\delta}$Allen Institute for Artificial Intelligence
```